# Блок под элементом (Ответы данные ранее оказались не рабочими)

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, есть `head` сайта, он имеет стиль:

```
<div id="navigations" class="default">
        <ul>
           <li style=" padding-top:4px;padding-right:60px;">
</a>
           </li>
            <li>
            <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" value="" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" />
            <div id="suggestions"></div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bloB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Geto</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fielo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">dobro</a></li>


                <div id="foter_space" style="float:right;">
                &nbsp;
                </div>


        </ul>
    </div>
#navigarions
left: 0px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
z-index: 99999;
}
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы под полем с `id search` всегда был блок? Как его зафиксировать именно под этим полем, т.к. проблемой является то, что фиксированные `margin` не помогают, поскольку меню сжимается по размеру экрана. Подскажите, что можно сделать в этом случае?
[image: Как показано на картинке блок suggestions блоком всегда находится под блоком search даже при увеличении и уменьшении страницы]

Comment: Уточните, блок который должен быть под полем поиска присутствует в вашем примере или находится вне UL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ели как на картинке то:

```
<style>
    #block {
        position:relative;
        width:200px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #suggestions {
        top:200px;
        position: absolute;
        width:inherit;
        height:300px;
        background:#333;
    }
    #search {
        width: inherit;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px;
    }
</style>
<div>    
    <div id="block">    
        <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" value="" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" />
        <div id="suggestions">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Могу предлжить целых 3 способа с учетом того что в блоке с id suggestions будет какой-то контент:

**Первый:**

```
    <div id="suggestions"><input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" value="" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" /></div>
    <style>
    #suggestions {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    }
    #search {
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    z-index: 99999;
    }
    </style>
```

**Второй:**

```
<li style="position:relative;"><input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" value="" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" /><div id="suggestions"></div></li>
   <style>
#search {
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
z-index: 99999;
}
</style>
```

**Третий:**

```
<li style="position:relative;"><div id="suggestions"></div><input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" value="" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" /></li>

    #suggestions {
    width: 100px;
    }
    #search {

    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left:-100px;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно поместить поле и блок под ним в один общий блок.